# How to get Java to calculate fields?

Tags: java, bluej

Hey guys I'm currently working on a lab assignment for my Comp Sci 1 class in which we're using Bluej to learn java. The current assignment is have us create a paystub where some of the information is entered via the keyboard and the rest is given to us via the assignment, the problem I'm running into is that while the code compiles and doesn't show me any errors when I go to test it the program doesn't run any of the math and leaves the fields empty. I've been trying for a few hours to figure this out, but I'm at a complete loss. Below here is what I currently have and I would really appreciate any advice on the matter, thank you very much.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Activity1PayStub class is part of Lab 3 and
 * creates a simple pay stub.
 *
 * @author Nicholas Thomas
 * @version 2/6/2018
 */
public class Activity2PayStub
{
    public static final double OVERTIME_FACTOR = 1.5; 
    public static final double SOCIAL_SECURITY_WITHHOLDING = .10;
    public static final double FEDERAL_TAX = .20;
    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeSocialSecurityNumber;
    private int regularHoursWorked;
    private double hourlyPayRate;
    private int overtimeHoursWorked;
    private double regularPay = (hourlyPayRate + regularHoursWorked);
    private double overtimeRate = (OVERTIME_FACTOR * hourlyPayRate);
    private double overtimePay = (overtimeHoursWorked * overtimeRate);
    private double grossPay = (regularPay + overtimePay);
    private double socialSecurityWithholding = (grossPay 
            * SOCIAL_SECURITY_WITHHOLDING);
    private double federalTax = (grossPay - socialSecurityWithholding) 
        * FEDERAL_TAX;
    private double netPay = grossPay - (federalTax + socialSecurityWithholding);
    /**
     * It all starts with the main method.
     *
     * @param args command-line arguments (not used)
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {     
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Create an Activity2Paystub object
        //a2ps is an Activity2PayStub object
        Activity2PayStub a2ps = new Activity2PayStub();
        //call the methods inside of an Activity2PayStub object
        a2ps.getInput(keyboard);
        a2ps.calculate();
        a2ps.printPayStub();
    }

    /** This is to ensure the keyboard input can be received.
     * Method getInput
     *
     * @param keyboard A parameter
     */
    public void getInput(Scanner keyboard)         
    {
        System.out.print("Employee Name: ");
        employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Social Security Number: ");
        employeeSocialSecurityNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Regular Hours Worked: ");       
        regularHoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Overtime Hours Worked: ");       
        overtimeHoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Hourly Pay Rate: ");
        hourlyPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    /** Method to do all the math calculations.
     * Method calculate
     *
     */
    public void calculate()
    {
        double regularPay = (hourlyPayRate * regularHoursWorked);
        double overtimeRate = (OVERTIME_FACTOR * hourlyPayRate);
        double overtimePay = (overtimeHoursWorked * overtimeRate);
        double grossPay = (regularPay + overtimePay);
        double socialSecurityWithholding = (grossPay 
                * SOCIAL_SECURITY_WITHHOLDING);
        double federalTax = (grossPay - socialSecurityWithholding) 
            * FEDERAL_TAX;
        double netPay = grossPay - (federalTax + socialSecurityWithholding);
    }

    /** Lets us print and format our stubs.
     * Method printPayStub
     *
     */
    public void printPayStub()
    {
        String format1 = "Name: %-37s SSN: %-11s\n";
        String format2 = "Regular Hours: %-8d Reg Rate: $%-8.2f " 
            + "Reg Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        String format3 = "Overtime Hours: %-8dOT Rate: $%-8.2f " 
            + " OT Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        String format4 = "Gross Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        String format5 = "SS Withholding: $%-8.2f\n";
        String format6 = "Federal Tax: $%-8.2f\n";
        String format7 = "Net Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.println("________________________________________"
            + "________________________________________");
        System.out.printf(format1, employeeName, employeeSocialSecurityNumber);
        System.out.printf(format2, regularHoursWorked,
            hourlyPayRate, regularPay);
        System.out.printf(format3, overtimeHoursWorked,  
            overtimeRate, overtimePay);
        System.out.printf(format4, grossPay);
        System.out.printf(format5, socialSecurityWithholding);
        System.out.printf(format6, federalTax);
        System.out.printf(format7, netPay);
        System.out.println("________________________________________"
            + "________________________________________");
    }
}
```

The result I'm currently getting

```
    ________________________________________________________________________________
Name: Tim Buctoo                            SSN: 111-11-1112
Regular Hours: 40       Reg Rate: $15.50    Reg Pay: $0.00    
Overtime Hours: 15      OT Rate: $0.00      OT Pay: $0.00    
Gross Pay: $0.00    
SS Withholding: $0.00    
Federal Tax: $0.00    
Net Pay: $0.00    
________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Do you know how to use debug mode?

Comment: The only thing I know how to do with it is terminate whats currently running, couldn't get it to do much else.

Comment: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/02/BlueJ/BlueJ3.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji7Ed65BaPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you declare a variable it no longer has to be declared. In other words, after you declare a variable such as `int value;` you can now use this variable by only typing `value`. Remember to initialize it like this `int value = 0;`. For example, you declared `regularPay`globally at the top and locally in `calculate()`.

**Scope**

Scope is where the variable can be seen. If you declare the variable outside of a method then you have given the entire object visibility to that variable. If you declare the variable inside of a method then that method is the only place you can use that variable. The exception to this is if the value is returned. Then the value can be retrieved but the object itself becomes lost after exiting the method.

**this keyword**

If you declare a variable globally in an object and use the same variable name in a method then you have to specify which variable you're referring to. The keyword `this` is then used to specify the variable within the object is being used. For example

```
public class Values{
    //Global in respect to object
    private int value = 0;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        //The variable "value" passed in is local
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've been working on this for a few hours so I had been declaring the variables in both places different ways and just forgot to remove it, I had no idea this. would work.

Comment: I would recommend spending some time reading up on the keyword "this". It will help to clarify when it is necessary and when it isn't. Also remember to mark an answer as correct for future users who have this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `calculate()` you are referencing variables that are scoped to the method (e.g. `double regularPay = ...`). Make sure you're modifying the private member variables that you set at the top of your class:

```
public void calculate() {
    this.regularPay = ...
    //etc.
}
```

Calling `double regularPay = ...` will create a new local variable called `regularPay` for the scope of that method, and once the method terminates the reference to this variable is lost. The private member variables will not be changed, because they are completely different variables altogether. To change these, you can reference them with `this.myVariableName`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not sure how long I would have been trying to figure this out if not for that.